# WRITE statement after button was clicked

Tags: abap

I want to use the abap WRITE statement after the button was clicked.
Right now nothing happens. Can someone help?

Heres my code:

```
TABLES: sscrfields.
SELECTION-SCREEN:
  PUSHBUTTON /33(10) submit USER-COMMAND start_search.

* button.click
AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'START_SEARCH'.
      WRITE: 'btn.click'.
  ENDCASE.

* button label
INITIALIZATION.
  submit = 'OK'.
```

Comment: Is there a real life scenario for this? Using `WRITE` doesn't work that way on selection screen

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that. Is there an alternative method to write something to the screen after a button was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can communicate with the user on the selection screen:

1. Use a [message](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapmessage.htm) that shows in the bottom of the screen;
2. Use a [popup](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73/7.3.16/en-US/47/b9487e01602fe2e10000000a42189d/frameset.htm);
3. Change the value of a [comment](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapselection-screen_comment.htm) on the selection screen.

Since I think the first one is the most elegant, here is the example code:

```
MESSAGE 'Button clicked' TYPE 'S'.
```

Just replace the `WRITE` statement you have now with the above and it should work. For a real solution you should or create a message in SE91 or a text element in your program.